Exploring the Action of Symmetric Groups on Tensor Products in Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces
I am working on a problem related to finite-dimensional vector spaces and their tensor products, specifically concerning the subspace $ I_k(V) $ generated by decomposable elements. Here’s a brief overview of the definitions and the problem I am trying to solve.
Let $ V $ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $ k > 1 $ where $ k \in \mathbb{Z} $. We define $ I_k(V) $ as the subspace of $ L_k(V) $ generated by decomposable elements of the form $ \varphi_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes \varphi_k $, where $ \varphi_i \in V^* $ and for some index $ i $, we have $ \varphi_i = \varphi_{i+1} $. Additionally, we define $ I_1 = \{0\} $.
The problem consists of showing the following statements about $ I_k(V) $:

If $ \alpha \in I_k(V) $, then $ \text{Alt}(\alpha) = 0 $.
$ I_k(V) $ is a bi-ideal, meaning that if $ \alpha \in I_k(V) $ and $ \beta \in L_s(V) $, then both $ \alpha \otimes \beta $ and $ \beta \otimes \alpha $ belong to $ I_{k+s}(V) $.
For any $ \varphi_1, \varphi_2 \in V^* $, the element $ \varphi_1 \otimes \varphi_2 + \varphi_2 \otimes \varphi_1 $ belongs to $ I_2(V) $.
If $ \alpha \in L_k(V) $ and $ \sigma \in S_k $, then we want to show that

$$
\alpha_\sigma = \epsilon(\sigma)\alpha + \theta
$$
for some $ \theta \in I_k(V) $.
I am particularly interested in the fourth point, which relates the action of the symmetric group $ S_k $ on $ \alpha $ and how it can be decomposed into a sum involving $ I_k(V) $.
Questions:

Can someone provide insight into how to prove the relationship described in point 4?
What tools or techniques from representation theory or multilinear algebra can be applied here?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Can you please say what $L_k(V)$ is in your notation? I don't think it is a standard notation.

Please also define $\alpha_\sigma$ and $\epsilon(\sigma)$.

$L_{k}(V)$ is the vector space of all $k$-linear maps from $V^{k}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (or another field it doesn't affect). Each element of $L_{k}(V)$ is a $k$-linear map, so $L_{k}(V)$ is a space of all such tensors (sometimes called $k$-tensors).

$\alpha=\varphi_{1}\otimes\varphi_{2}\otimes\cdots\otimes\varphi_{k}$ then $\alpha_{\sigma}=\varphi_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\varphi_{\sigma(2)}\otimes\cdots\otimes\varphi_{\sigma(k)}$ where $\sigma$ is a permutation of $k$ elements.

$\epsilon(\sigma)$ si the sign of the permutation, +1 if it makes an even number of changes and -1 if the number of changes is odd.
